# array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, arrays

I tried the below code for print a random value from an array for 70 times but i am getting an error as such : ' array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array'.

```
$q= array("top","below","right","left");
function ran(){
    $rand_keys = array_rand($q, 1);
    return $rand_keys[0];
}

for ($m=0; $m <70 ; $m++) {
    ran($q);
    echo ran();   
}
```

Comment: You should pass `$q` to the function. Otherwise, `$q` is out of the function's scope and is undefined.

Comment: funtion ran needs to accept a parameter, like: function ran($q)

Comment: I guess your ran() function has to have a declaration of the $q variable. I'm not expert of php but I think that the $q in ran() shadows the array $q

Comment: use `error_reporting(~0);` at the top of your code and configure your development server to show all errors.

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are not normally visible inside functions. You should put `$q` in the function parameter list:

```
function ran($q) {
    $rand_keys = array_rand($q, 1);
    return $rand_keys[0];
}
```

Then call it as:

```
echo ran($q);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add $q as a parameter.
Also, you should return the value of $q at index $rand_key.
You kinda miss used array_rand return value.

Giving you this code :

```
$q = array("top","below","right","left");

for ($m = 0; $m <70 ; $m++) { 
    echo ran($q).' ';
}

function ran($q){
   $rand_keys = array_rand($q, 1);
   return $q[$rand_keys];
}
```